# xQuery get value of attribute with multiples

Tags: xquery

I am trying to get the exact text of an attribute using xQuery. The issue i am finding is that i have multiple elements with the same name that have an attribute with a colon in the text.

Example

```
    <body>
      <tag xlink:href="1.jpg" position="float" orientation="portrait"/>
      <tag xlink:href="2.jpg" position="float" orientation="portrait"/>
      <tag xlink:href="3.jpg" position="float" orientation="portrait"/>
      <tag xlink:href="4.jpg" position="float" orientation="portrait"/>
    </body>
```

Some examples i have used are the following

```
for $graphic in $body//tag
  return element tag { ($graphic//@*[name()="xlink:href"]) },

element tag { $body//graphic/@*[name()="xlink:href"] }
```

Both of my current examples give some output but not whats expected. The intended output that i am looking for is...

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple XPath expression to return the attributes :

```
$body//tag/@*[name()="xlink:href"]/data()
```

Given the HTML snippet in question, output of the above XPath/XQuery is exactly as what you are looking for, see **[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/2Q4sU45wO)**

Alternatively, if you mean to get single string value in such format :

```
string-join($body//tag/@*[name()="xlink:href"], "&#10;")
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

For me this works:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace xlink = "http://xlink.im";

let $body := <body>
      <tag xlink:href="1.jpg" position="float" orientation="portrait"/>
      <tag xlink:href="2.jpg" position="float" orientation="portrait"/>
      <tag xlink:href="3.jpg" position="float" orientation="portrait"/>
      <tag xlink:href="4.jpg" position="float" orientation="portrait"/>
    </body>
for $graphic in $body//tag
  return $graphic/@xlink:href
```

Simply try to return `$graphic/@xlink:href`.

Answer (score 0):

The part before a colon in an xquery element or QName is the namespace.

In your example xlink would be the name space. In the example XML xlink should be define in the XML. A lot of times its defined in the root node.

If you need to xpath to an element with a namespace make sure the namespace is define in your xquery and just put it in the xpath

```
body/tag/@xlink:href
```